# Is there a way to pipe an output constructed of printk messges to grep on console?

Tags: linux, grep, console, pipe, printk

I have an utility created that prints output using printk. For eg.

```
printmsg.c:
void main() {
     printk(KERN_DEBUG "Message alert id:XXXX!\n");
     printk(KERN_DEBUG "Message alert id:YYYY!\n");
     return;
}
```

If run this utility on the system, it prints the message like below on the console

```
#./printmsg
Message alert id:XXXX!
Message alert id:YYYY!
```

Whereas, if i run this application to pipe the output to grep, it doesn't work.

```
#./printmsg | grep XXXX
Message alert id:XXXX!
Message alert id:YYYY!
```

I am aware that the printk messages to kernel log buffer and dmesg to print the log buffer. With dmesg options to print output on stdoutput.

However, i am looking for an option to pipe the output to grep instantly when the utility runs and the output dumps on the console.

Limitation: printk can't be compromised here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct your shell script on this way:

```
#./printmsg 2>&1| grep XXXX
```

and this is because (with high probability) `printk` function send message to STDERR, not STDOUT

Comment: printk goes to kernel ring buffer unlike printf that goes stdout or stderr. 2>&1 doesnt/wont work in my case